# How to cook eye of round roast?

Tags: beef, roast, roast-beef

What are my options for cooking an eye of round roast? What's the best way to cook this cut of meat to minimize the potential for it to dry out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eye of round is an excellent cut for braising. You can braise it in stock or red wine. An example recipe would be the classic Beef Bourguignon.

It's also a perfect candidate for slow-cooking in a crock pot, as well as simply roasted in the oven. If cooking it in the oven, use a thermometer and don't cook it past medium. An overnight marinade can be used prior to roasting for additional flavor as well.

Comment: If I'm going to roast in the oven, what temperature and for how long?

Comment: 350F, about 40 mins per pound for medium rare. But really, use that as a guideline - the thermometer is your friend. Simply pull the roast out 10 degrees _before_ your desired doneness. You may want to try this [high temperature roast recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/high-temperature-eye-of-round-roast/Detail.aspx) instead. I haven't, but it's highly rated.