# Pressure Cooker vs. Slow Cooker for Moist Meat

Tags: slow-cooking, pressure-cooker

This question: [Why does meat in the crockpot always end up dry?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21511/why-does-meat-in-the-crockpot-always-end-up-dry) discusses challenges and potential solutions to getting moist meat while cooking with a slow cooker.

If I were to switch to a pressure cooker, would that be another method to keep meat moister?  Or, if I'm not following the suggestions in the above post (in particular, using the right kind of meat), would a pressure cooker not really help me much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the wrong kind of meat (= tender meat low in connective tissue), the pressure cooker will make it much worse. With this meat, the more energy goes into it (and the pressure cooker gives it more over the same amount of time), the worse it gets. You really have to prepare it as a steak or roast.

It would be an interesting thing to try out on the right kind of meat though, since there you want to break down the connective tissue, and the pressure cooker could be better at it.